# Expectation Values of Spin Matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, representation-theory

Let's say we have some set of spin matrices based on total angular momentum $j = 1$. We have 2 matrices of importance to consider:

$$ J_x = \frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, J_z = \hbar \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Assume that we are in the state $j_x = -\hbar$. How would we determine $\langle J_z \rangle, \langle J_z^2 \rangle, \Delta J_z$

Note: This is a homework question (part of a MUCH larger question), so please only guidance, no answers. Our textbook is "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, Third Edition - Griffiths & Schroeter"

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly you're stuck on, the notation $\langle J_z\rangle$ means $\langle \phi |J_z|\phi\rangle$ in which $|\phi\rangle$ is the state the system is in. Is that helpful?

Comment: I mainly am still confused as to what $\langle \phi | J_z | \phi \rangle$ really means, as it was poorly explained in the book, I'll take a look at it with what you said!

Comment: Yes you need a state $\vert \phi\rangle$ to be able to evaluate an average value.

Comment: @TheAkashain You might find it helpful to know that in the $3-$dimensional Hilbert space you're currently working in, $\Bbb C^3$, $\langle \phi|$ is a row vector, $J_z$ is of course a matrix (operator) and $|\phi\rangle$ is a column vector, also that $\langle\phi|^\dagger=|\phi\rangle$.